# Getting the highest value sequential number in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a list of values in one column. But this contains obsolete entries:

```
PIL.7762.25.xml
PIL.7762.24.xml
PIL.7762.23.xml
PIL.7762.22.xml
PIL.7762.20.xml
PIL.7762.19.xml
PIL.7762.18.xml
```

From this list I only need `PIL.7762.25.xml` which is the highest/latest value.

This is one example in a column with 600+ entries.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use **array formula**. But unfortunately **array formula** could not be used in Excel online (Reference: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/98535/excel-online-enter-array-formula).

If you want to use Excel desktop application, here is the formula:

```
=MAX(VALUE(MID(B3:B11, 10,FIND(".",B3:B11,10)-10)))
```

Don't forget **Ctrl** + **Shift** + **Enter** to activate the array.

Hope it is useful.